# Essential elements of a modern national constitution

Tags: law, constitution

**If one were to write a constitution from scratch, today, what are the essential elements that a national constitution would need to specify?**

From the US Constitution and Bill of Rights, we get descriptions of how the government is organized, the creation of the three branches of government and the rights of individuals.  Other constitutions will specify a national religion. I'm hoping for a survey of common elements that show up in modern or near-modern constitutions.  I don't care about the verbiage used, just the general elements that are specified by the constitution.

Common Constitutional element seem to be:

- Structure of the top-level governmental bodies
- Specification of the rights of individuals
- Specification of the national relgion, or prohibition of a national religion.

What have I missed?

Comment: If you make no assumptions about prior political structure or cultural history, then it seems far too broad. Everything in a constitution is based on elements of previous political structures that they want to keep, and elements of previous cultures they want to protect.

Comment: @Giter The continued existence of Israel, Saudi Arabia, the UK and otherstates with an unmodified constitution also allow the trivially narrow answer that nothing is essential, and it can all be dealt with in the whole body of law.

Comment: Do you suppose that there are legal requirements on what must be in a constitution? Where would those requirements come from?

Comment: I would say *if you have a constitution*, that the only essential aspect is a means to change it.

Answer (score 3):

There are [some countries with no explicit constitution at all](https://www.quora.com/Which-democratic-countries-do-not-have-a-constitution), including places like the UK, Israel, and New Zealand. So empirically, the minimum required in a codified constitution is basically nothing.

Comment: Not having a constitution is not an answer to a question starting with "If one were to write a constitution". Not having a constitution effectively changes your type of government system...

Comment: @rubenvb: OP is asking what are essential elements of a constitution. The fact is that there are countries with no constitution. Ergo, the answer is that there are no essential elements of a constitution.